# Simplifying my JSON to build a array.

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to take my JSON input and generate a easy array to search in, but it is as far as I can tell giving me some trouble.

First of, this is my JSON as is, loaded from a file:

```
{
   "teams": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "boat": "Test",
         "name": "Palle Test"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "boat": "Test 2",
         "name": "Name Test 2"
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "boat": "Test 3",
         "name": "Name Test 3"
      },
      {
         "id": "4",
         "boat": "Test 4",
         "name": "mller"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this or minimise the number of arrays?

I have been using the following code to preview my array, but I am trying to get it to search for id and then print the values for id, boat and name.

```
  $json_url = "teams.json";
  $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
  $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo  '</pre>';
```

Comment: You only have one array. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Minimise number of arrays for what?

Comment: Why........?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really quite simple. There is no need to convert a perfectly good object into an array, it only makes life more complex.

The only array you have in your data structure is the `teams` array and that is easily processed like this

```
$json = '{
   "teams": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "boat": "Test",
         "name": "Palle Test"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "boat": "Test 2",
         "name": "Name Test 2"
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "boat": "Test 3",
         "name": "Name Test 3"
      },
      {
         "id": "4",
         "boat": "Test 4",
         "name": "mller"
      }
   ]
}';

$data = json_decode($json);

//print_r($data);

foreach ($data->teams as $object) {
    if ( $object->id == 2) {
        echo 'boat is ' . $object->boat . ' and name is ' . $object->name . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

And the result of the above example would be

```
boat is Test 2 and name is Name Test 2
```

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly. Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.